# Differences between 读 and 阅读?

Tags: grammar, usage

If I am not wrong then both of them means read. So what are the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

读 = **read** ; **read out**. (it can read refer to reading a whole book, or just a single word)

阅读 = **read** (refer to reading of a book, a publication, or even a single sheet flyer-- something that contains meaningful context)